# Magento2: Indexes every time Processed

Tags: magento2

3 indexes are marked in red and have the status every time Processed
[image]

does anyone know why I'm being processed and how to solve it?

When I try run in SSH php bin/magento indexer:reindex then:

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product Categories index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product Price index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:35
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

@update

I have reset and try again reindex but ger error deadlock:
[image]

and now 2 index still proccess:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, reset all the indexer by running below command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and then reindex all again.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It will work.

Comment: @ Abhishek Panchal I have update my topic.

Comment: Is it fresh Magento setup?

Comment: https://www.tigren.com/fix-deadlock-error-reindexing-magento-2/

Comment: Abhishek, no is no fresh Magento.  I try this and again reindex but sill return this issue deadlock during reindex